# Подключение WPForms к сайту на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, html5, wordpress-плагины

Я написал сайт и натянул его на пустую тему ,

Есть ли инструкции, как к форме моей на сайте подключить WPForms?

P.S. Я искал, и все говорят про как подключить форму к странице на WP, но я так и не нашёл, как это сделать, если сайт на коде.

Comment: Что значит в Вашем понимании: "к форме моей на сайте подключить wp-forms"? WP Forms -- это Drag & Drop Form Builder что предполагает то что форму Вы делаете при помощи этого плагина.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите плагин WPForms, создайте в нём форму. Используйте шорткод формы, который виден в плагине, для вывода формы:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[wpforms id="xxxx"]' );
```